# Вопрос по задаче "Стандартное отклонение"

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, математика, статистика

[image: Стандартное отклонение последовательности]

Задачу решил. Но менее оптимально. В примерах решения других учащихся был такой код. Можете ли объяснить почему мы можем посчитать выражение под корнем, не раскрывая квадрат разности (a-b)**2? 
Мне кажется код возводит в квадрат сумму X и S и вычитаем их, после извлекаем корень. Не понимаю согласно каким математическим правилам мы можем это сделать.

```
# решение без применения списка
x = int(input())
n = summ_squares=summ = 0

while x != 0:
    n += 1
    summ += x
    summ_squares += x ** 2
    x = int(input())
print(((summ_squares - summ ** 2 / n) / (n - 1))**0.5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Не понимаю согласно каким математическим правилам мы можем это
>   сделать.

раскрытие скобок и вынесение констант за знак суммы

[image: вот так]

Comment: Ого, круто! Спасибо большое за такой подробный ответ

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста как преобразовали эту часть  от третьего до четвертого равно. Не  понимаю откуда появилось n и почему пропал xi в средней компоненте

Comment: @AlexSapsay Равенство ( s= среднее арифметическое ) умножаем на n, получаем что (сумма x_i)=ns,это второе слагаемое. у третьего слагаемого то что под знаком суммы не зависит от i, это просто n одинаковых слагаемых s^2

Comment: Спасибо за хорошие пояснения, теперь я точно разобрался

Comment: Смотрю на решение и ничего не понимаю. Напишите попроще пожалуйста.

Comment: @deNIK88 какой именно переход не понятен из семи?

Comment: откуда в этом месте появилось "s"? У Вас написано: ∑x^2 - 2s(ns) + ns^2. При раскрытии скобок должна быть "x". То есть формула должна получиться такой: ∑x^2 - 2s(nx) + ns^2. Поэтому далее сокращение не получается. Как так-то?

Comment: @СветланаР. ∑x_i = ns